# Java Linked List maxElement recursive

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have been working on an assignment for awhile now one of the methods I have to define is a recursive solution to finding the max element in the list. I feel like my solution is close, but I keep getting the last element inserted back, instead of the max element. Can someone point out what I need to do to solve this?
     *** I have been instructed not to use pre-built classes or methods. ***

```
        int maxElement () {

    if (head == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node current = head;
        return maxElement (current);
    }
}

private int maxElement (Node current) {     
    Node max;
    // If our next node does not exist, our current node has to be max
    if (current.getNext() == null) {
        return current.getKey();
    }
    //  
    else {  

        if (current.getNext().getKey() > current.getKey()) {
            // Assign the larger key as our new max
            max = current.getNext();
            return maxElement (max);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return maxElement (max.getNext());
}
```

Comment: What is the second else statement in maxElement for?

Comment: It's for another condition to be evaluated, but I need to figure out what that condition is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly elegant solution:

```
public Node max(Node node1, Node node2) {
    if (node1 == null || node2 == null)
        return node1;
    else
        return max(node1.getKey() > node2.getKey() ? node1 : node2, node2.getNext());
}
```

It is called using `max(head, head.getNext())`.

If you specifically need to avoid passing the current maximum into the method then:

```
private static Node currentMax;

private Node maxElement(Node node) {
    if (currentMax == null || node == null)
        return currentMax;
    else if (node.getKey() > currentMax.getKey())
        currentMax = node;
    return maxElement(node.getNext());
}
```

This is called with `currentMax = head;` then `maxElement(head)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the current max in your recursion:

```
public Node max() {
    return maxAux(root, null);
}

private Node maxAux(Node current, Node currentMax) {
    if(current == null) {
        return currentMax;
    }
    if(currentMax == null || current.getKey() > currentMax.getKey()) {
        return maxAux(current.getNext(), current);   // current is the new max
    } else {
        return maxAux(current.getNext(), currentMax);
    }
}
```

Comment: The function definition for the recursive helper method MUST be as follows:

private int maxElement (Node current) {...}

Comment: So how do you know what is current max? This is clearly an error. You have to keep track of both your current node and the current max.

Comment: @JeanLogeart the max could be a static field. Not pretty but I suspect that's what his teacher is assuming.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this solution with only one parameter, other than a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
private Node head, max;

int maxElement () {

    if (head == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node current = head;
        return maxElement (current);
    }
}

    private int maxElement (Node current) {     

        // If our next node does not exist, our current node has to be max
        if (current.getNext() == null) {
            current = this.max;
            return this.max.getKey();
        }
        //  
        else {  

        if (current.getNext().getKey() > current.getKey()) {
            // Assign the larger key as our new max
            this.max = current.getNext();
            return maxElement (current.getNext());
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return maxElement (max.getNext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, SklogW! I appreciate the answer